# GeoPoint in the map is different from Google map display position

Tags: android, location

I use LocationManager to get location. Then convert location to GeoPoint and show it in the map. Why it is so different from Google map display position?
This is the method to get the location:

```
mLocationManager = (LocationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
        criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
        criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
        criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
        criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
        final String strLocationProvider = mLocationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
 mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(strLocationProvider, 1000, 0, 
                new LocationListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        double geoLatitude = mLocation.getLatitude()*1E6;
            double geoLongitude = mLocation.getLongitude()*1E6;
            GeoPoint currentGeoPoint = new GeoPoint((int)geoLatitude,(int)geoLongitude);
            mapCon.animateTo(currentGeoPoint);                  }

                    @Override
                    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                            Bundle extras) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
     public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {      
     int lat = (int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6);
     int lng = (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6);
     GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(lat, lng);
     OverlayItem overlayitem4 = new OverlayItem(point, "You Are Here", "Boulder, CO"); 
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Projection to translate between GeoPoints and  the Points on the Map.

```
Projection projection = mapView.getProjection(); 

GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(lat, lng);

Point myPoint = new Point();
projection.toPixels(point, myPoint);
```

Then you would use myPoint in your OverlayItem